# Navigation view not showing upon custom actionbar in android

Tags: java, android-studio

Navigationbar not showing upon the custom action bar what should i do in android 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDRCw.png)

Comment: You need to show some code

Comment: but you have an actionbar in this image.